# Get owner-name/device-name of iPad using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, cordova, appmobi

I want to use it to display a welcome message "Hi [owner name]".

**Is it possible to get the owner-name/device-name of an iPad using html5/javascript?**

Or using html5 and another framework e.g. phoneGap, appmobi etc.

Comment: I think this value is not set on an iPad. Theres is only the name of the device, which is often not the name of the owner.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this.
The only thing that is possible is to detect that a person is using iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PhoneGap/Cordova API, and specifically the [Device API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device) which allows you to obtain the following details:

- device.name
- device.cordova
- device.platform
- device.uuid
- device.version